# Is there anything that can tell me precisely how the cross sectional area/radius of a snake changes over length?

Tags: zoology

I am trying to 3D model a green anaconda which I thought would be simple, then I realized there is actually this very gradual change in thickness from a minimum around its neck to a maximum somewhere in the middle then to another minimum around its tail.

Is there some kind of specific terminology or archive I can look up to get precise measurements? Regular google searches aren't doing it and there is a high amount of variation in this thickness gradient between species.

Comment: Maybe just pick a function with such properties and adjust the parameters until the snake "looks right"?

Comment: @electronpusher that would work only if there is data. OP is asking for data, not modeling tips.

Comment: If there was a perfectly straight snake that had both top and side pictures of it next to a ruler, then I could take measurements until it "looked right", but unless I have at least that, there's no accurate way to approximate it other than shear guessing.